# Qt Multiple GraphicsEffects

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Is there a way in Qt5 to apply a QGraphicsEffect to a widget, even when one of its parent widgets already has a QGraphicsEffect applied to it?
When i try the following:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class ParentWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        effect = QGraphicsBlurEffect(self)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
        effect.setBlurRadius(0)

class ChildWidget(ParentWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setObjectName('reviewControlArea')
        effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(widget)
        widget.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

        self.layout.addWidget(widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()

    cw = ChildWidget(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(cw)

    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The stdout says:

```
QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Qt's graphics effects are a bit of a bastard child. You'll need to look into Qt's source code to figure that out. It looks like a bug to me. Your code sample has some extraneous voodoo in it. Effects don't need parents, they'll be owned by the widget you set them on. You also don't need a main window - this seems a common misconception. Simply `show()` the `ChildWidget`. Finally, you don't need any custom widget classes at all. A parent `QWidget`, with a grid, and two labels as children, one of which needs an effect set.